# Upload more than one file PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

I have to upload 2 images. One is a product image and another one is QR. I need to insert in to MySQL database the URL of each image. I managed to get the URL of each image registered in the database and upload one of the two images, the first one, but the image that corresponds to the QR, the second one, it is not being uploaded to the server, I do not receive any error message.

This is the table in MySql
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMzYt.jpg)

Product image is "product_image" and that of the QR code is product_qr

This is the user "interface" created with "modal" in PHP-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtEdn.jpg)

Then I put the piece of code that corresponds to the function that connects to the database and that is responsible for uploading the files:

```
$type = explode('.', $_FILES['productImage']['name']);
$type = $type[count($type)-1];
$typeQR = explode('.', $_FILES['productQR']['name']);
$typeQR = $typeQR[count($typeQR)-1];

$url = '../assests/images/stock/'.uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
$urlQR = '../assests/images/stock/'.uniqid(rand()).'.'.$typeQR;
if(in_array($type, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 
'PNG')) ||
in_array($typeQR, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 
'PNG')) ) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name']) ||
is_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name']) ) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], $url) ||
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name'], $urlQR)) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name, product_image, brand_id, 
categories_id, quantity,rate, active, status, description, position_store, status_product, reference, product_qr)
        VALUES ('$productName', '$url', '$brandName', '$categoryName','$quantity', '$rate',
         '$productStatus', 1, '$productDescription', '$positionStore','$statusObject', '$reference', '$urlQR')";
```

This is the "modal" code:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="max-height:450px; overflow:auto;">

    <div id="add-product-messages"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productImage" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Imagen: </label>
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <!-- the avatar markup -->
                    <div id="kv-avatar-errors-1" class="center-block" style="display:none;"></div>
                <div class="kv-avatar center-block">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="productImage" placeholder="Imagen del producto" name="productImage" class="file-loading" style="width:auto;"/>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productQR" class="col-sm-3 control-label">QR: </label>
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <!-- the avatar markup -->
                    <div id="kv-avatar-errors-1" class="center-block" style="display:none;"></div>
                <div class="kv-avatar center-block">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="productQR" placeholder="Imagen QR" name="productQR" class="file-loading" style="width:auto;"/>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
```

As I say, everything works fine, but the QR image does not upload to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work when you test it locally ?

It seems like there is an permissions problem. Have you checked permissions on server where you are trying to upload those files ?

You need Write permissions to upload files to folders. Depending on which client you are using, right click on the folder ( in your case 'assets' or 'assets' and 'images') and check whether they have write access.

Or maybe there's a problem with the `if` statement:

`if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], $url) || move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name'], $urlQR))`

try using `&&` instead of `||` like this :

`if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], $url) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name'], $urlQR))`

Comment: All files are being token from same folder and being saved is same server folder, and because the first file is uploaded correctly, then the second one would have to do since all is ordered from same code piece. Before to come to this, I logged as a Admin too.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with 
   `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], $url) ||
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name'], $urlQR))`

Try using `&&`  instead of  `||`

Comment: Dear RamazG You are right, must be "&&". Please write the answer below and I will clic "confirm" as the right answer. Thanks.